importing .msh and build 3D mesh
I have a .msh file for a volume mesh generated via GMSH.
I want to import it and read it in order to build a volume mesh for further FE simulation in Mathematica.
I have been able to get the nodes coordinates and elements nodes, but unable to build the volume mesh.
The .msh file can be downloaded here
https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=a78fee39-4b1b-45c2-b90c-a4a764fd557e
(*Step 1:Import the raw content of the.msh file*)filePath = \
"path/to/file.msh";(*Replace with the actual file \
path*)mshContent = Import[filePath, "List"];

(*Step 2:Extract the node numbers and coordinates sections*)(*Node \
numbers are in lines 11 to 4091 (4081 lines)*)
nodeLines = mshContent[[11 ;; 4091]];

(*Coordinates are in lines 4092 to 8172 (4081 lines)*)
coordinateLines = mshContent[[4092 ;; 8172]];

(*Step 3:Parse the Node Numbers and Coordinates and combine them*)
nodesWithCoordinates = 
MapThread[
Function[{nodeLine, coordLine}, {ToExpression[nodeLine], 
 ToExpression[StringSplit[coordLine]]}], {nodeLines, 
coordinateLines}];

(*Step 4:Extract the element data section*)(*Element data is located \
between lines 8177 and 16334 (8160 lines)*)
elementLines = mshContent[[8177 ;; 16334]];

(*Step 5:Parse the elements data*)
(*Each line has the three vertex indices*)

elements = 
Map[Function[elementLine, 
Module[{data}, data = ToExpression[StringSplit[elementLine]];
 Rest[data] (*remove the element number from the list*)]], 
elementLines];

Print["First 5 Nodes with Coordinates: ", 
Take[nodesWithCoordinates, 5]];
Print["First 5 Elements: ", Take[elements, 5]];

First 5 Nodes with Coordinates: {{1,{-0.0423465,0.0215736,-0.291592}},{2,{-0.0390912,0.0237885,-0.29254}},{3,{-0.0406605,0.0222658,-0.294617}},{4,{-0.0434024,0.0216819,-0.28486}},{5,{-0.041646,0.0233357,-0.287176}}}

First 5 Elements: {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,7,9},{8,11,9}}


Have you tried FEMAddons?

I have installed FEMAddOns but when I run ImportMesh it does not work...

Can you show all of the code? For example, how do you create the boundary mesh? In other words, what exactly is the problem?

Seeing that the mesh file was written by Gmsh, I recommend exporting the mesh from Gmsh using the STL format.  When I used the command line gmsh femur.msh -0 -o femur.stl to convert to STL format, Mathematica 14.1.0 was able to import the mesh from femur.stl and returned a MeshRegion.

yes, but then it is a surface mesh and Mathematica cannot build a volume mesh on that...

Use ToElementMesh[meshRegion] to get a full mesh. It would be very helpful if you can include the code and the error messages that you get.

apparently I cannot because the surface is not closed...I am trying to solve the issue but not successfully so far...

this is the error I get: TetGenTetrahedralize::reterr: Tetrahedralize returned an error, 2.

So you surface is not closed. Try FindMeshDefects and RepairMesh and see if that brings you forward.

I tried both, but nothing works...

I have tried to run MeshLab directly from mathematica (because I have many geometries to repair), but no success so far...

How have you generated these geometries in the first place?

From this one, which is not closed neither: https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=22380ab8-869a-4075-aa78-346bc0ba3103. it has been obtained from CT-scans
